# Mocking jquery function in qunit - Dexter should receive a valid object and method combination in arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I'm trying to add testing to my javascript app, using QUnit and [Dexterjs](https://github.com/leobalter/DexterJS) for mocking functions. In this case I'm trying to mock the $.getLocation():

```
    QUnit.test( "testGetUrlVar", function() {

        var baseUrl = "http://www.example.com?ip=192.168.0.1";

        var fakeLocation  = Dexter.fake( document, '$.getLocation', function() {
                            return baseUrl.slice(baseUrl.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');;
                        }),
                theUrlVar;

                theUrlVar = $.getUrlVar('ip');

                equal(theUrlVar,'ip','ip var found');

                fakeLocation.restore();

    });
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
testGetUrlVar (1, 0, 1)Rerun443492 ms
    Died on test #1 @http://localhost:5985/estante20140819/_design/library/test/urltoolsTests.js:1:1 : Dexter should receive a valid object and method combination in arguments. Ex.: window & "alert".
```

Here's the code I'm trying to mock:

```
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = $.getLocation();
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },

  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  },

  getLocation: function(){   
      return window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  }

});
```

**UPDATE:**

I've narrowed down the error to the following code in dexter.js and the error is because typeof(obj[method]) is undefined.

```
   if ( !obj || typeof( obj[ method ] ) !== 'function' ) {
            throw 'Dexter should receive a valid object and method combination in arguments. Ex.: window & "alert".';
        }
```

Comment: Looks like Dexter wants the object context for the method, but you're using `document` when `$` is on the window. Did you try: `Dexter.fake( window, '$.getLocation', function() { ...});`

Comment: I tried that before and just double checked again. Same error using window. Thanks!

Comment: Too bad... sorry, I'm not familiar with Dexter.

Comment: Oh... just thought of this... does Dexter need _only_ the function name as the second arg? Maybe this: `Dexter.fake( window.$, 'getLocation', function() { ...});`

Comment: Good though, but that wasn't it either :(.

Comment: Can you put a `debugger;` statement there and tell us what `obj` and `method` are at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly when Dexter tries to mock the function, it's either not finding `$` or `$` doesn't have the method `getLocation`.

So, where does `$` come from; is it definitely visible in the scope where you're calling?

The call to Dexter should definitely be:

```
...
Dexter.fake( $, 'getLocation', function() {...});
...
```

But you should make sure that `$` is in scope, that the `$.extend(...)` function really has been run before your tests start.

Comment: I moved getLocation to a plugin:
$.fn.getLocation = function(){...};

Comment: The the call was Dexter.fake( $.fn, 'getLocation', function() {...});

Comment: Aha. Will change my answer, then, since it seems to be accepted as correct.  Ah. I see, actually I misread you.  So it *was* correct but you've changed things?

Comment: Yes, I had already made that that change before I got your answer. But I hadn't gotten to work yet. I didn't revert my code to test your answer, but I believe it was correct. Although I wasn't sure how to know if $.extend() had been executed. So factoring out the function took that need away.